# Mysql server on MAMP 4.1.1 won't start in macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: mysql, mamp

My MAMP 4.1.1 MySQL server will not start on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

I have uninstalled MAMP and reinstalled v4.1.1

There are NO files in the htdocs folder and NO databases in the mysql56 folder.

The only things in there are the folders:

`performance_schema`, `mysql`, and the file `mysql_upgrade_info`

I’ve tried the following:

• restart MAMP as well as computer shut down and restart
• set ports to default

• terminal to kill all sql processes:

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

response is: `No matching processes were found`

• chmod the folder:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

After many hours of searching around for solutions I finally uninstalled MAMP 4.1.1 and installed MAMP 3.5.2 and it works.

If someone knows why MAMP 4.1.1 MySQL server won’t start on Sierra 10.12.5 let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it but you will need to delete the program and download the new version.